# Install Out of Browser application from Silverlight application running in browser

Tags: silverlight

Recently we are doing work in a WebSite project which is totally based on Silverlight 5. Our Online application will be this . Now I want to give an application( this application is made in Out of Browser and user can install on their desktop) free to all my user who are registered.

Once they successfully login in my Silverlight enabled web site then there will be Link called "Download" and this will install an OBBS(Out of browser application) in client's desktop machine.

How to do that, any suggestion will helpful .

Comment: This might be helpful: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/08/12/silverlight-out-of-browser-force-install-pattern.aspx